# react-leaflet remember zoom and center position

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to set the zoom and the center of leaflet map to previous location of the user. So, I want to remember the zoom and center level.

I can't really figure it out. I found the method "onZoomEnd". But how do I set on rerender of the map the state of zoom and center to the previous one. this is my code:

```
  const map = useRef(null);

  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(6);
  const [center, setCenter] = useState([50, 10.5]);

  return (
  <Fragment>
   <Map
    boundsOptions={{padding: [10, 10]}}
    center={center}
    className={rootClassName}
    gestureHandling
    ref={map}
    whenReady={fitMapBoundsToFG}
    onZoomEnd={(e) => setZoom(e.target._zoom)}
    zoom={zoom}
    zoomSnap={0.25}
  >
```

Comment: You can store the last known center and zoom in local storage. retrieve and set these values once component gets mounted.

Comment: Sorry I can not really figure it out. I now tried to setZoom in the onZoomEnd metohd but it always swap instant back when I zoomin